# How can I create a compressed archive consisting of the largest files from multiple directories?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, compression

I want to write a script which will create a single compressed-archive file consisting of the largest files above a certain threshold from multiple directories. For example, I would like to know how to take the 5 largest files above 2MB and put them into a compressed archive file called `largestfile.tar.gz`. Here is what I have so far:

```bsh
du -a $path | sort -n -r | head -n 5 > diskspacefile.txt
file=$(cat diskspacefile.txt)
while read p; do
    filesize=echo $p | awk '{print $1 }'
    if [ $filesize > 2000000 ] 
    then
        zipfile=`echo $p | awk '{print $2 }'`
        tar -zcvf largestfile.tar.gz $zipfile
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately this does not appear to work. When I run it I either get only a single file in the archive or no files at all. For context, the directories I'm interested in applying this to are `/root` and `/boot` (i.e. these will be the values for the `path` variable in the code snippet).

Comment: The code is not complete.

Comment: `du -a $path | sort -n -r | head -n 5 > diskspacefile.txt
file=$(cat diskspacefile.txt)
while read p; do
filesize=`echo $p | awk '{print $1 }'`
if [ $filesize > 20000000 ] ;
then
zipfile=`echo $p | awk '{print $2 }'`
tar -zcvf largestfile.tar.gz $zipfile
fi
done < diskspacefile.txt

Comment: Still at least `done` is missing.

Comment: looks like your target tar-file is static `largestfile.tar.gz`. For every iteration, same file is getting overwritten.

Comment: yep... i want to put all file in a one zip file that is largestfile.tar.gz @franklinsijo

Comment: @SuganthanRaj If you want all the files in a single archive you should use the `-r` option: `-r, --append     append files to the end of an archive`. Otherwise your `tar` command will create a new archive with only a single file in it each time.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding in your question. `tar` won't produce a `zio` file. They're completely different formats.

Comment: The code below i used in my script.

`du -a $path | sort -n -r | head -n 5 > diskspacefile.txt
while read p; do
filesize=`echo $p | awk '{print $1 }'`
if [ $filesize > 1000000000 ] ;
then
zipfile=`echo $p | awk '{print $2 }'`
tar -rvf largestfile.tar.gz $zipfile
gzip largestfile.tar
echo $zipfile
fi
done < diskspacefile.txt`

Comment: @SuganthanRaj Does this work? You are trying to append to a compressed archive, move the compression to outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that we can use `find` to generate a list of all the files larger than 2MB in a given directory:

```bsh
find . -type f -size +2M
```

We want to extract the 5 largest files from this list. To do that we can use the `-printf` option to print out both the file path and the file size (in bytes), as follows:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +2M -printf '%s:%P\n'
```

Now we can sort these results by file size (in descending order) and the top five results from this order list:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +2M -printf '%s:%P\n' | sort -rnk1
```

Next we remove the filesize to retrieve the relative paths to the 5 largest files above 2M in the current directory:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +2M -printf '%s:%P\n' | sort -rnk1 | head -n 5 | cut -d: -f2-
```

Finally we can pass this list of file paths to the `tar` command in order to create a zipped archive of these files:

```bsh
tar czf largestfile.tar -T <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +2M -printf '%s:%P\n' | sort -rnk1 | head -n 5 | cut -d: -f2-)
```